# Reverse proxy on a Node.js server using Nginx?

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, digital-ocean

Okay, I'm about at my wits end here.  I have an Express server running an Angular app. Using this guy's tutorial http://antrikshy.com/blog/deploy-an-expressjs-app-on-digital-ocean-complete-succinct-guide/

I have my app running at my Digital Ocean IP address + port 8000. I've created an upstart service so it's always running.  I also installed Nginx and its Welcome screen is up at my DO IP address.  So now I need to configure nginx so I can access my site with just the IP address.

I tried doing what the guy in the tutorial did, but mine just isn't working... What am I doing wrong?

Here's my set up: 
 
Using WinSCP I uploaded my app into "/home/stuffie" on my server, then I uploaded a .conf file called "KamiAng.conf" into the "/etc/init" folder as you can see in  the image below.

[image: app folder snapshot]
**Note: The app.js file is the file that starts my node server.

Here's the contents of KamiAng.conf

```
# Goes in /etc/init/

description "Keep my site up"

start on startup
start on filesystem and started networking
stop on shutdown
respawn

chdir /home/stuffie/KamiAng
env NODE_ENV=production
env PORT=8000
exec node app.js
```

And this works! When I type in "sudo start KamiAng" my site stays up at IP:8000 even when I close out of the terminal.  Like I mentioned above I installed nginx and it's running at my IP address.

So now I'm trying to configure ports with nginx.

In the "/etc/nginx/conf.d/" folder I've added a file called "kamicon.conf" 
Here's that file:

```
# Goes in /etc/nginx/conf.d/

upstream kamicon {
    server **myIP**:8000;
}

server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name stuffiestephie.com www.stuffiestephie.com;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_pass http://kamicon/;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
 }
```

According to the tutorial I linked to, at this point I should be able to enter "sudo service nginx reload" and run my app again using "npm start".  This however, does not work.

[image: errors]

After starting entering "sudo service nginx reload", I enter "npm start" which results in an error because my package.json isn't in "/home/stuffie/" so then I change directories to "KamiAng" (where the package.json file is) and enter "npm start" and I get the errors seen in the above image.

I'm losing it here... What am I doing wrong? I just really need this server up.

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: I never used Digital Ocean and I don't read the tutorial, but I would to suggest to alter `listen 0.0.0.0:80; ` to `listen 80;` and `proxy_pass http://kamicon/;` to `proxy_pass http://kamicon:8000;` ( but, perhaps could  `proxy_pass http://www.stuffiestephie.com:8000`.

Comment: Have you made sure that you don't have old node processes running... Do a ps and check. It looks like you might have an old node process hogging the port. Killall!

Comment: And what are you using npm start for? Is that an equivilent syntax for npm install?

Comment: So if you don't have a start script defined then npm start will try to run node server.js which won't work because you have app.js. Try and kill all processes and run node app.js clean. Should work. Then go get pm2.

Answer (score 0):

try changing `chdir /home/stuffie/KamiAng` to `chdir /home/stuffie/KamiAng/` in KamiAng.conf